# Is "line-height: normal;" a bad idea?

Tags: css

I have observed some rather inconsistent HTML page rendering behavior when CSS `line-height` property is set to `normal`. I have also found a [blog post by Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/05/06/line-height-abnormal/) where different inconsistencies of `line-height: normal;` are discussed, here is just one quote:

> Here’s the punchline: the effects of declaring `line-height: normal` not only vary from browser to browser, which I had expected—in fact, quantifying those differences was the whole point—*but they also vary from one font face to another, and can also vary within a given face*.

In my case i observed that adding some Unicode symbols, for example the envelope symbol "✉", changes the line block height if `line-height` is set to `normal`. Setting `line-height: 1.2;` fixes the problem.

My question is: is there any reason at all to use `line-height: normal;`? It behaves so unpredictably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In principle, a `normal` value for `line-height` (either via defaulting, or by explicit setting) is “normal”: browsers are expected to use a value that is suitable for the font being used. This variation should not be a surprise: it’s implied in the [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height).

This is supposed to help with a problem like this: you declare `font-family: a, b, c, d, sans-serif`, but you don’t know which of the specific fonts (if any) is available in each computer, or what the default sans-serif font might be. These fonts might require different line heights, for good appearance. The browser knows which font it is using, so it can pick up a line height for it, from its internal table.

On the practical side, browsers might not select the value well; it tends to be generally a little too small. On the typography side, line height should be selected on the basis of several considerations, not just font face but also the type of text (e.g., texts with a lot of diacritic marks require larger line height) and especially the measure (column width, line length): long lines require larger line height.

So in general, it is best that the designer sets the line height, with due consideration of the different aspects.

This also avoids the problem you describe: when a line contains glyphs from different fonts, each font may have a different default line height associated with it. For example, the envelope symbol is included in a few fonts only, so the odds are that the browser is forced to pick it up from a font different from the one you have declared.

This is what causes uneven line spacing when you mix fonts. It’s not the height of the glyph that matters but the line height of its font. For example, adding a mere period “.” in Cambria Math font, when available, causes huge line spacing—unless you set `line-height` to a specific value.

Comment: If i have understood correctly, the benefit of `normal` value is that the browser can set the actual value based on the font it is really using. However, as far as i know, there is no way for a designer to specify style rules based on the actual font the browser is using. This means in my opinion that `normal` is rather useless: the only way to customize it is to override it completely, losing all its benefits. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Alexey There is no universal right or wrong. It depends on the situation. If you need the lines to be 20px apart, by all means use `20px`. If you want the browser to determine the most "natural" line height for your text, and you don't mind that the block of text is a few pixels larger on one browser than on another, you can use `normal`.

Comment: That said, I fail to see how you would "customize" the value of `normal`.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any reason at all to use line-height: normal;

Yes - the property is there so you can use it when you specifically have to reset line-height to browser default in case you've set it somewhere on parent element.

Why and when you would want to do that depends on what you are implementing and whether or not you care about crossbrowser pixel perfect designs or not.

Comment: I can ask the question differently: is there a reason to use the browser default (which is `normal`)?

Comment: @Alexey - this is a trick question - since you could always set it trough whole webpage or just leave it to normal - depends on your laziness and project budget. Let's say you've set a line-height of 20px for all elemnets on page like `* {line-height:20px}`, but you also set a `font-size` of `30px` on your `h1` and `25px` on your `h2` tag. Since you decided that you do not want to bother with line-height of your headings you just set it to normal - if you left it on 20px your text would get cropped off or overflap if the heading was longer than one line. So in this case it is useful to use it.

Comment: Also I doubt this question can be answered with one single answer - it really depends from project to project and what you are doing with it.

Comment: Adding `* {line-height:1.2}` does not require a lot of budget and fixes most of the problems :).

Comment: @Alexey - I know - that was a very abstract sample :) Like I said - if you want to use normal - than use it - if you want to set it each time and remove crossbrowser inconsistencies than set it. This is kinda a "perfectionist" vs. "whatever-gets-it-done" debate. Even that blog post has kinda mixed thoughts on it :)

Answer (score 0):

"normal" is the default value for "line-height". You explicitly declare line-height: normal to over-ride.

Example:

```
h1 {
    line-height: 150%;
}

h1.normal {
    line-height: normal;
}
```

If you look at the above snippet I have declared a line-height of 150% for h1 tag. In-case I want a particular h1 tag to behave normally [browser specific line-height], then I over-ride it using "normal"

Its true the normal line height varies on different browsers

Comment: Not only it varies between different browsers, but also between different symbols of the same font.